# Using data.tree for txt format trees and getting kids for each level

Tags: r, tree

I have the following tree in txt file (you can copy paste and save it into txt file):

```
R> res
J48 pruned tree
------------------

Petal.Width <= 0.6: setosa (50.0)
Petal.Width > 0.6
|   Petal.Width <= 1.7
|   |   Petal.Length <= 4.9: versicolor (48.0/1.0)
|   |   Petal.Length > 4.9
|   |   |   Petal.Width <= 1.5: virginica (3.0)
|   |   |   Petal.Width > 1.5: versicolor (3.0/1.0)
|   Petal.Width > 1.7: virginica (46.0/1.0)

Number of Leaves  :     5

Size of the tree :  9
```

This is my input file. I would like to get the list of each node (father) and its kids of the tree (it is only an example). I would like to know if I can transfer this txt format into a tree by using `data.tree`. And how can I get the kids of each level (father)?

Comment: Have you tried anything?